# Matching values of two data frames based on multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a two datasets

```
cycle <- c(160, 160, 150, 158, 180) 
split1 <- c(2, 2,4, 6, 8) 
split2 <- c(10,10, 12, 14, 16) 
df1 <- data.frame(cycle, split1, split2) 
df1
  cycle split1 split2
1   160      2     10
2   160      2     10
3   150      4     12
4   158      6     14
5   180      8     16

cycle <- c(160,150,190,180,161,150,140,179)
split1 <- c(2,4,12,8,2,4,32,8)
split2 <- c(10, 12, 18, 16, 10, 12, 21, 16)
df2 <- data.frame(cycle, split1, split2)
df2
  cycle split1 split2
1   160      2     10
2   150      4     12
3   190     12     18
4   180      8     16
5   161      2     10
6   150      4     12
7   140     32     21
8   179      8     16
```

I want to match the values of df1 and df2 and label the df2 values based on two conditions:

1- If the values of all three columns i.e cycle, split1, and split2 are exactly the same then assign a row with the label "Same" otherwise "Different".

2- If the difference of only cycle value from df1 and df2 is +1 or -1 and the rest of the row values are the same then assign a row with the label "Same" otherwise "Different".

The output should look like this

```
  cycle split1 split2      Type
1   160      2     10      Same
2   150      4     12      Same
3   190     12     18 Different
4   180      8     16      Same
5   161      2     10      Same
6   150      4     12      Same
7   140     32     21 Different
8   179      8     16      Same
```

I was successful in achieving the first condition as below

```
df1<- df1 %>% mutate(key = paste0(cycle,split1, split2, "_"))
df2<- df2 %>% mutate(key = paste0(cycle,split1, split2, "_"))
df2 %>% mutate(Type = ifelse(df2$key %in% df1$key, 'same', 'different'))%>%
  select(-key)

  cycle split1 split2      Type
1   160      2     10      same
2   150      4     12      same
3   190     12     18 different
4   180      8     16      same
5   161      2     10 different
6   150      4     12      same
7   140     32     21 different
8   179      8     16 different
```

but having a problem achieving the second one.

Any idea how to do this efficiently?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your original `df1` and `df2` (without the generation of the new column `key`), you could use

```
df2 %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = c("split1", "split2"), suffix = c("", ".y")) %>% 
  mutate(
    type = coalesce(
      ifelse(abs(cycle - cycle.y) <= 1, "same", "different"), 
      "different")
    ) %>% 
  group_by(rn) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-rn, -cycle.y)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  cycle split1 split2 type     
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>    
1   160      2     10 same     
2   150      4     12 same     
3   190     12     18 different
4   180      8     16 same     
5   161      2     10 same     
6   150      4     12 same     
7   140     32     21 different
8   179      8     16 same
```

Comment: There is one problem. In actual data, the df1 has duplicate values which are producing duplicate values in the df2 that I don't need. I want the size of the df2 file the same.

Comment: Could you make an example with this problem and explain how to handle it?

Comment: for example if df1 is : cycle <- c(160, 160, 150, 158, 180)
split1 <- c(2, 2,4, 6, 8)
split2 <- c(10,10, 12, 14, 16)
df1 <- data.frame(cycle, split1, split2)
Then the code you provided will produce 10 rows instead of 8.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for: try replacing `df1` in the code above with `df1 %>% distinct()`.

Comment: It is giving the error "Problem adding computed columns in `distinct()`.
x Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`."

Comment: @ Martin Gal I have edited the data in the question, I hope now you can help me to achieve my desired output. Thank you

Comment: @SorathAbbasi Updated the answer. Perhaps it helps you now.

Comment: Thank you it worked very well. However, I have another query. Is it possible if we also check the +1 and -1 difference in the split1 and split2 column as well and then label them as same or different?